# Mapping from the z-plane to the w-plane

Tags: complex-numbers, transformation

I'm struggling with this question

Show that the  transformation w=z-1/z maps |z-1|=1 in the z-plane to |w|=|w-1| in the w-plane.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint...start by writing $$z=1+e^{i\theta}$$ and simplifying $$z-\frac 1z$$
You should end up with the real part equal to $\frac 12$ which is equivalent to the required locus